# Meaning of "べつにパリパリ健康だよ"

Tags: translation

(it might be バリバリ)

I know what べつに　and　健康　mean individually, but I don't know how to translate this phrase....

Comment: Please edit your post to give us your best-guess effort.  Without that, I bet your post will be closed as "off-topic" as a translation request, which are not supported here at the Japanese StackExchange.  See the post at [We don't do translations or proofreading](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/796/what-questions-are-not-allowed-on-japanese-language-se/799#799).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree that this is a mere translation request but might as well answer it.
What you heard was most likely バリバリ健康 which is a colloquial way of saying "super" healthy.
Not the best translation but for just knowing what the phrase means, it get's the point across.

Comment: I love that パリパリ also means _"crunchily, crunchy-crunchy"_.  :)